# ng2-bootstrap pagination and bootstrap table integration error

Tags: typescript, pagination, angular, ng2-bootstrap

I'm trying to integrate [ng2-bootstrap pagination component](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#pagination) and bootstrap table.

I have a simple bootstrap table that is loaded with ngFor directive:

```
<tr>
    <th *ngFor="#col of cols">{{col.header}}
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="#row of rows">
        <td *ngFor="#col of cols">{{row[col.field]}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The `rows` content is determined by the pagination component:
I have an array called `data` that contains a bunch of entries for the table. The array length is used to determined the `totalItems` of the pagination component:

```
<pagination class="pagination-sm"
            [(ngModel)]="page"
            [totalItems]="data.length"
            [itemsPerPage]="itemsPerPage"
            [maxSize]="maxSize"
            [boundaryLinks]="true"
            (pageChanged)="onPageChange($event)">
</pagination>
```

The table's `rows` variable contains only the entries of the current page. This is done by using the `pageChange` event provided by the pagination component:

```
onPageChange(page:any) {
        let start = (page.page - 1) * page.itemsPerPage;
        let end = page.itemsPerPage > -1 ? (start + page.itemsPerPage) : this.data.length;
        this.rows = this.data.slice(start, end);
    }
```

So far so good...
The problem is that entries can be removed from the `data` array.
If the pagination bar is pointing to the last page and then entries are removed from the `data` array, the below error is shown in console:

`Expression 'rows in App@9:8' has changed after it was checked.`

A live example can be found here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5zxamBiWISBpEmXYP5UK?p=preview
Just click the `last` button and then `cut data`.

Any advice?

Comment: I have been unable to get [itemsPerPage] to work correctly.   I set the value and called it directly after closing tag on the div holding my *ngFor directive.   Did you have to do anything in your table to limit the items per page?  i am getting all items on one page.

Comment: @Winnemucca 
The itemPerPage is a property on the pagination directive, it has no effect on the table. So yes, you have to limit the table data. In the above plunker it is done by the onPageChange function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, I decided to change the `cutData` function a little bit. 
Before each data cut, the current page is reset to 1:

```
cutData(){
  this.page = 1;
  this.onPageChange({page: this.page, itemsPerPage: this.itemsPerPage})
  this.data = this.data.slice(0, this.data.length/2);
}
```

Now everything seems to work as expected.

**Another option** (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005#issuecomment-195991516) for a similar issue)  is to manually trigger change detection for the component after `rows` change:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

(...)

onPageChange(page:any) {
    let start = (page.page - 1) * page.itemsPerPage;
    let end = page.itemsPerPage > -1 ? (start + page.itemsPerPage) : this.data.length;
    this.rows = this.data.slice(start, end);
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```