# How to implement ngb-pagination in angular4

Tags: angular, pagination, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to include ngb-pagination, how to make that work. this may be a duplicate but since that answer is not working I am posting it again.

I have no clue how to make it work

```
 <tr *ngFor="let data of reportsData;let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
        <td>{{data.time_stamp}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="50" [page]="1" [maxSize]="5" [rotate]="true" [boundaryLinks]="true"></ngb-pagination>
```

Comment: your question is missing a lot of details. You should include at least the errors you get in your console!

Comment: actually, I don't know how to implement it. I cannot find correct docs for that @Hamed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at this working demo on plunker: [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3B013fJoNNY7jyZuLQI0?p=preview)

you can check the official docs over here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination

```
<ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="70" [(page)]="page" [directionLinks]="false"></ngb-pagination>
```

in the component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-pagination-basic',
  templateUrl: 'src/pagination-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdPaginationBasic {
 //setting the default page
  page :number = 1;
}
```

another alternative is to use the ngx-pagination as a simpler soultion take a look at the github repo: [Here](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination#demo)

Comment: Hameed, I saw that too, Can you help in implementing with that table I have mentioned above.

Comment: I was trying to implement ng-bootstrap pagination. thanks for the alternative suggestion that was nice too...

Comment: how are you handling page size on this?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't do it yet but I think I found an answer for question every beginner ask (I am too):
Why ngb-pagination doesn't work?

You should **slice your JSON data by pages** and in component HTML iterate through sliced data (NOTICE: this is only view code example!).

`<div *ngFor="let item of pagedItems">{{item.name}}</div>`

More info you can find on this [article](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/23/angular-2-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google) and in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874587/ng2-bootstrap-pagination-and-bootstrap-table-integration-error).