# How to set dynamic value in [collectionSize] using ngb-pagination in angular 6/7?

Tags: pagination, angular6

I have used `ngb-pagination` for dynamic pagination for my table. And I have an issue to set `collectionSize` value dynamically.

**What I have set**

```
<ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="totalDataCount" [(page)]="page" [boundaryLinks]="true" (pageChange)="loadPage($event)"></ngb-pagination>
```

I have also tried with `[(collectionSize)]` but not works.

**In .ts file**

```
totalDataCount;

// In API call function 
this.apiService.POST(obj,'getList')
  .subscribe((response)=>{         
      if(response.code == 1){            
        this.totalDataCount = response.data.total;
        this.driverList = response.data.list; 
        console.log(response);           
      }
  },(error)=>{
    console.log("error");
  })
```

When I console `totalDataCount`, It's console proper value. I think I'm missing very minor thing,but I don't not know what is that.

**Note :** If I used `[collectionSize]="15"` as a fixed value then it works.

What I want to set is, For ex. I have a 35 records and I have set perPage value to 10 then my pagination will be set to [1,2,3,4] dynamically.

I have used it from this reference links.

[Plunker ref](http://plnkr.co/edit/ADGtMRQClwEvifmUZeID?p=preview)

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243393/how-to-implement-ngb-pagination-in-angular4)

Right now I have set pageSize= 5;

As you can see in image, I have a value of 6 so expected pagination is **[1,2]** but now I got only **1** in pagination.

[image]

Comment: Know one has any idea ?

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1219

Comment: @Chellappan I'm already use this link as I mention in my question.

Comment: You mean if your collection is 6 and pagesize is 5 then the pagination not showing as expected?

Comment: Yes @Chellappan

Comment: I tried in stackblitz it showing expeted result: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsiuk1

Comment: Is is issue for `pageSize` ?

Comment: Did you add page size in your code?

Comment: No , I haven't added yet

Comment: Default pageSize is 10 that's why you are getting 1 button

Comment: ok I'll try and let you know.

Comment: @Chellappan It works for me ! Issue is missing pageSize. Please add you answer. I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default pageSize of ngb-pagination is 10 you should assign the value as per your need

**component.html**

```
<ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="6" [pageSize]="pageSize" [(page)]="page" aria-label="Default pagination"></ngb-pagination>
```

component.ts

```
 pageSize='5';
```